# Wp-Fullcalendar not showing up

Tags: wordpress, fullcalendar

i´m still searching for an answer why my calendar is not showing up... 
I´m workin on an multisite WordPress and want to implement WP-Fullcalendar but i think i do something wrong. 
I think when you´re looking into my code you´ll perhaps laught but i dont know the anser why my calendar don´t show. 
Thank you for your help! Greetings

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script>

       $(document).ready(function() {
            var date = new Date();
            var d = date.getDate();
            var m = date.getMonth();
            var y = date.getFullYear();

            var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                editable: true,
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },

                events: [
    {
     title: 'All Day Event',
     start: '2017-04-01'
    },
    {
     title: 'Long Event',
     start: '2017-04-07',
     end: '2017-04-10'
    },
    {
     id: 999,
     title: 'Repeating Event',
     start: '2017-04-09T16:00:00'
    },
    {
     id: 999,
     title: 'Repeating Event',
     start: '2017-04-16T16:00:00'
    }
   ],

                // Convert the allDay from string to boolean
                eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
                    if (event.allDay === 'true') {
                        event.allDay = true;
                    } else {
                        event.allDay = false;
                    }
                },
                selectable: true,
                selectHelper: true,
                select: function(start, end, allDay) {
                    var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                    var url = prompt('Type Event url, if exits:');
                    if (title) {
                        var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                        var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'event.php',
                            data: 'title='+ title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&url='+ url ,
                            type: "POST",
                            success: function(json) {
                                alert('Added Successfully');
                            }
                        });
                        calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                                {
                                    title: title,
                                    start: start,
                                    end: end,
                                    allDay: allDay
                                },
                                true // make the event "stick"
                        );
                    }
                    calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
                },

                editable: true,
                eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
                    var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'event.php',
                        data: 'title='+ event.title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id ,
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function(json) {
                            alert("Updated Successfully");
                        }
                    });
                },
                eventResize: function(event) {
                    var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'event.php',
                        data: 'title='+ event.title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id ,
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function(json) {
                            alert("Updated Successfully");
                        }
                    });

                }

            });

        });

    </script> 
    <style>

        body {
            margin-top: 40px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;

        }


        #calendar {
            width: 900px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='calendar'> ?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're loading jQuery twice. Remove one of them and it should resolve your issue.